# Graph API Not able to access "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages" endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, authorization, microsoft-identity-platform

I am trying to access "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages" API by JAVA SDK provided by Microsoft.

I am using the below code.

```
 final AuthorizationCodeCredential authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId("b****08f-*****-4d49-****-cba7d9a****c")
            .clientSecret("8***7Q~GW0N******Y_N*****Zi******") 
            .authorizationCode("0.AVUAoIQSV...")
            .redirectUrl("http://localhost/auth-responses")
            .build();
```

Now it is giving me error like "**The tenant for tenant guid '571284a0-****-****-****-a94eea6c6b3f' does not exist.**"

I tried the Same thing by postman, here I tried to get token by below end point.

"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token"

after getting the token I am using it in "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages" as Bearer Token. Still, I am getting the same issue.

But the token I am receiving in every case is not same as graph explorer **Access Token**

[image]

If I copy Graph Explorer Access Token and use it in postman then it gives me the desired result.

**I am using a personal account for all of this process which ends with "@outlook.com".**

I want to know why I am getting different access tokens than graph explorer access tokens and why that access token is not able to access the endpoints.

Comment: Hello @shubhgaikwad, May i know how you are signing in to the graph explorer ? Is the Personal account of yours a user or admin in the tenant? the client_id you are using are you the owner of it ? also can you please add the screenshot of the postman token request body parameters [like this](https://i.imgur.com/fjKab7P.png) ? as i tested it from postman using auth code flow and i was successfully able to run the graph api as well..

Comment: Hi,
I am signing to graph explorer using a user that I have created under that tenant.

Comment: Ohkay the same way I am also doing .. can you please add the screenshot for postman

Comment: Yes Sure.
[link SS](https://imgur.com/JCdgxvD.png)

Comment: I am trying to create a service that will fetch messages but signing to graph explorer wont help. I am trying to get messages by this endpoint 
 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?$filter=(receivedDateTime ge 2021-10-15T00:00:08Z) and (receivedDateTime le 2021-10-16T00:00:08Z)

Comment: can you use this url instead of the url you are using : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238341/discussion-between-ansumanbal-mt-and-shubh-gaikwad).

Comment: I am using the below endpoint to get auth_code. [SS](https://i.imgur.com/lw8NoxM.png)

after that I am using that auth-code in token API I am getting token but then I am getting error like this.  [image](https://imgur.com/IEJ9m4l.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

The access token generated from the Graph Explorer will be different from the access token generated from the Postman. This is because, the access token generated from graph explorer uses only the user credentials. The access token generated from postman uses client id and the client secret along with user credentials.

If the app registration supports Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox), then only you can use personal account to generate the access token and use it to call the request for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages only if the app registration have Microsoft Graph mail.read delegated permissions.

Paste the below URL in the browser. The code will be generated. Copy the code.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=app-client-id
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&scope=mail.read
```

Make the below POST request in the postman to generate the access token :

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Headers : 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body : 
client_id: App Client ID
grant_type: authorization_code
scope: user.read%20mail.read
code: Code received in the first step
client_secret: Client Secret Generated in the App
```

[image]

Copy the Access token and make the below get request in the postman to read the messages :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages

Headers:
Authorization : Bearer access-token
```

[image]